# Can I change the maximum elevation value of a DEM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, elevation

I have a DEM derived from photogrammetry using DroneDeploy and it has come out very nicely in terms of resolution, but the elevation values are all wrong.

I know the exact elevation of the highest point in the DEM, so can I somehow tell ArcMap this to correct the elevation values?

Comment: Please take the effort to conduct some research. A quick search, on this site, for "change raster value" yielded many results. Take a look at "con" or "conditional statements" in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 3):

Please keep in mind that DEM's derived from lidar or photogrammetry can have +/- outliers. These should be screened before interpolating a surface but, sometimes we are just stuck with the product. I have had lidar derived DEM's that actually had bird hits in the returns that were not addressed and introduced some very unrealistic values. There is also the fact that sometimes the interpolation algorithm itself, introduces spurious values.

If there are known quantities in the surface (eg., known maximum elevation) then you can get quite tricky and rather than just truncating the values can actually use surrounding values to adjust to a realistic value. This is the power of raster algebra and the ability to nest statements. You can apply this type of analysis in the raster calculator. Here is some pseudo-code that you can follow.

```
Con(dem > 5000, FocalStatistics(dem, NbrRectangle(3,3,MAP), "MEAN"), dem)
```

What this statement does is apply the condition of any cells > 5000 are replaced with a focal mean of the surrounding 8 cells else the values of the dem are used. Please note that if you have large contiguous areas of spurious values you need to consider a different approach or even better, acquire the raw data and address it before interpolation.